# Adobe Edge set transform rotate property

Tags: jquery, rotation, transform, adobe-edge

I'm trying to script the rotation property of an element in Adobe Edge, but can't work out the syntax.

I'm trying this:

```
var element = sym.$("Rectangle");
element.css("transform", "rotate(25deg)");
```

But it doesn't change the rotation at all.
Using this exact same method works for other CSS properties, eg:

```
var element = sym.$("Rectangle");
element.css("left", 150+myVar);
```

Anyone know how I can access the transform:rotate property here?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

which browser are you testing with?
apparently, there's no official support for the transform property.
so you have to use a modified version of this based on your browser.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp

Answer (score 0):

This is what I used to handle a variety of browsers. This would be needed any time there is a difference in how different attributes are assigned.  You'll see what I mean below with this example. I put this in the 'click' event to wiggle a business card when clicked.

If a transformation works in one browser but not another, you can look up the attribute at w3schools.com and it will tell you if there are browser differences.

```
// Get us a random rotate transform value between -5 and 5
var rotate_val = Math.floor((Math.random()*10)+1) - 5;

// Get instance of this element
var card_element = sym.$("wr_business_card");

// Set a random rotation for the business card when clicked
card_element.css("transform", "rotate(" + rotate_val + "deg)");
card_element.css("-ms-transform", "rotate(" + rotate_val + "deg)");     /* IE 9 */
card_element.css("-webkit-transform", "rotate(" + rotate_val + "deg)"); /* Safari and Chrome */
```